# How to inject a CSS StyleSheet at runtime in an Angular Component

Tags: css, angular, angular-components

I need to inject a stylesheet into a component at runtime. Basically depending on user configuration settings a theme is picked and dependending on the active theme the CSS url changes.

Static injection via `styelUrls` doesn't work for this since that's static at compile time.

Nor does it seem to work when I directly inject the style link into the component:

```html
<link [href]="themeLink" rel="stylesheet"  *ngIf="themeLink" />
```

I've tried a few variations here - interpolation, using an `@import()` style - none of it seems to work with a dynamically assigned value.

The resources have been added to the included resources and **it works if I hardcode the above link to a specific style**. But setting the value at runtime gives me an error:

> core.js:6228 ERROR Error: unsafe value used in a resource URL context (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

which is fair.

But I can't seem to find a way to dynamically set a style sheet at runtime.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you try binding the result of `DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(themeLink)`?

Comment: No - didn't know that was a thing. Checking now. Thanks! Yes that works. Want to post that as the answer? `this.themeLink = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("themes/" + appModel.configuration.theme + "/theme.css");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent the error by disabling the Angular sanitization with the help of the `bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl` method of the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer):

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  let themeUrl = "themes/" + appModel.configuration.theme + "/theme.css";
  this.themeLink = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(themeUrl);
}
```